# Setting pointer to an already initialized variable?

Tags: expression-manipulation, memory

Consider a generic expression `myvar` which is not yet initialized to any value. If we want to create a reference (pointer) to `myvar`, we can simply set:

```
pointToMyvar = myvar;
```

Now if we go ahead and initialize `myvar` to some value:

```
myvar = 5;
```

we see that our pointer properly accesses the correct memory location to retrieve the value:

```
pointToMyvar
```

> `5`

And, of course after `myvar` is changed again

```
myvar = 7;
```

the pointer knows about it

```
pointToMyvar
```

> `7`

However, now that `myvar` is initialized, it seems that we cannot create any further pointers to it. If we now try

```
pointToMyvarAgain = myvar;
```

and change `myvar` yet again

```
myvar = 10;
```

we see that the new reference does not actually refer to `myvar` but rather just to the integer that was stored in `myvar` at the moment of assignment:

```
pointToMyvarAgain
```

> `7`

Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way how I could define a pointer to `myvar` (same as `pointToMyvar` above), **after** `myvar` has been initialized to some explicit value? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Can you provide an example / some context on when such an object would be useful to you?

Comment: Would `pointToMyvar := myvar` meet your needs?

Comment: Will [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/5478) be a good duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one those times when it is important understand the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html). You can get the behavior you are looking for with `SetDelayed`, although you should be aware that you are not creating a pointer. The Wolfram Language does not support pointers as such.

```
pointToMyvar := myvar
myvar = 5;
pointToMyvarAgain := myvar
```

> `{pointToMyvar, pointToMyvarAgain}`

So far everything looks the as it did when `Set` was used for all assignments. But now:

```
myvar = 42;
{pointToMyvar, pointToMyvarAgain}
```

> `{42, 42}`

So with `SetDelayed`, it does matter whether or not `myvar` has a value when the assignment is made. Examining the definition of `pointToMyvarAgain` in the kernel

```
Definition @ pointToMyvarAgain
```

shows

> `pointToMyvarAgain := myvar`

Because `myvar` is stored in the definition unevaluated, it appears to act as pointer.

Also see [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/3066)